# Assigning the same parameter value multiple times in pdo execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I originally had an SQL statement, this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(friend_one) AS pending_count , COUNT(friend_two) AS requests_sent   
FROM friends
WHERE friend_one OR friend_two = ?
AND status = ?
```

In which I assigned my parameters like :

```
$pending_friend_count_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $status_one));
```

However, the query was not getting the results I wanted. Someone showed me a different way of doing it, but it has the variable `$user_id` in it multiple times, so I do not know how to adjust the code to be able to use a parameter.

You can see the new query here:

http://rextester.com/KSM73595

Am I able to just do

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN `friend_one` = ? THEN 1 END) as `requests_count`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `friend_two` = ? THEN 1 END) as `pending_count`
FROM `friends`
WHERE ? IN ( `friend_one` , `friend_two` )
  AND `status` = ?

$pending_friend_count_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $user_id, $user_id $status_one));
```

Comment: Use named parameters `:userid` instead of `?` when feeding `['userid'=>$user_id]` to execute.

Comment: @Xorifelse Could I pot those in execute, like this? execute(array(':userid', $user_id,  $status_one));

Comment: updated the comment, but keep in mind, you can't mix them so all have to be named.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thanks. I wasn't aware you could do that. Feel free to leave an answer as this helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using PDO you have the ability to use named parameters, however in your question you want to use 1 parameters for multiple values and that means emulation has to be on:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

Now you can do the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = :userid AND userid = :userid");

$stmt->excecute([
  ':userid' => 1
]);
```

Resulting in:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = 1 AND userid = 1"
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you're passing in an array for parameters, you can use the keys `:0`, `:1`, etc

Comment: Are there any security risk in activating this emulation?