# Using the same POST value twice within a PDO PHP script | mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The second time the POST value `:supplier` is used the script does not write to the database. Without this second instance everything writes as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'dbname';
$userdb = 'username';
$passdb = 'password';
$charset = 'utf8'; 

if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['type'] , $_POST['number'] ,$_POST['supplier']  )) {

    // Connect and create the PDO object
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$namedb;charset=$charset", $userdb, $passdb, $options);

      try{
        $conn->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare( ' INSERT INTO `Equipment` (name, type, number, supplier, status, managed_by )
VALUES (:name,:type,:number,:supplier,"Ready", :supplier) ' );


    $stmt->execute([
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'type' => $_POST['type'],
        'number' => $_POST['number'],
        'supplier' => $_POST['supplier'],
    ]);
```

Comment: Give the 2nd occurance a unique identifier `:managedBy`.

Comment: But it is the same exact value as `:supplier` do I somehow set them equal to each other?

Comment: ... or just use unnamed placeholders, `?`. Then it could just be `$stmt->execute([$_POST['name'], $_POST['type'], $_POST['number'], $_POST['supplier'], $_POST['supplier']]);`.

Comment: If you give it a unique identifier, you can still pass through the same data. `$stmt->execute([..., 'managedBy' => $_POST['supplier']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 options:

1. Give the 2nd occurance a unique identifier `:managedBy`. See example below.
2. `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);`
3. Use `?` instead of named parameters (as pointed out in the comments)

The 2nd option (`$db->setAttribute...`) will allow you to use the same identifier multiple times. Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40682033/296555. There are security implications with this method. I would stay clear but leaving it here as an option for future readers.

**EDIT**

An example of using unique identifiers:

```
// Notice that we're using a uniquely names placeholder: `:supplier` and `:managedBy`
$stmt = $conn->prepare( ' INSERT INTO `Equipment` (name, type, number, supplier, status, managed_by )
VALUES (:name,:type,:number,:supplier,"Ready", :managedBy) ' );

// Notice that we are referencing those uniquely named placeholders below
// but using the same data `$_POST['supplier']`. 
$stmt->execute([
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'type' => $_POST['type'],
    'number' => $_POST['number'],
    'supplier' => $_POST['supplier'],
    'managedBy' => $_POST['supplier'],
]);
```

Comment: in your referenced post the user uses the same variable twice with the option, whay must replace the second one with another variable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: I set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,` but it is still not working, Is this incorrect?

Comment: Note: If you enable emulation, you should do [a few other things to prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/12202218#12202218)

Comment: True - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not. In this case, going to unnamed placeholders or giving all placeholder unique names probably makes the most sense.

Comment: your first point is Give the 2nd occurance a unique identifier :managedBy  but in the iinked post is written $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = **:userid** AND userid = **:userid**");  and nothing must be replaced according to the post

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I rather not enable emulation for the security risk, I am little confused how to give a unique identifier

Comment: @PeterDavon I wouldn't enable it either. Honeslty, just switch all of your placeholders such as `:supplier` to `?`, then you don't even have to have the key in your `execute()` array, you just have to pass the variables in the same order as the query.

Comment: I just ended up using a different identifier, I appreciate your help

Comment: @nbk - my linked resource is meant for #2 in the list. But as other commenters have pointed out, this is probably not the simplest route to take.

Comment: @PeterDavon - I think your issue is resolved but I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I have one more question that I am struggling with: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57082866/11752827